# Alinco DX70 TH at 10W

Tags: hf, alinco

Is it possible to make the Alinco DX70 TH operate at 10W PEP? The radio seems to be 100W and I read somewhere that you could switch it to 50W, but since my licence currently limits me to 10W, I'd like to see if that's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, page 2-9 of the manual shows:

[image]

[source](http://www.alinco.com/pdffiles/)